# How the meaning of these sentences change on changing the tense?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense, conditional-constructions

> If he asks you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.
>
> If he will ask you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.
>
> If he asked you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.
>
> If he should ask you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

I am wondering to find out the difference between these, which I believe may be in subjunctive mood also.

An edit:I am not sure about the third sentence but I certainly have seen sentences like this-

> If **you added** a screenshot of what you are trying to press, it would be helpful.

Comment: The *ask* after which we use subjuntive means *request* not *question*. More over you don't have a subjunctive after *ask*.  They are in a way reporting sentences in different tenses and the possible answer that may be given. And I think the difference between them is that they are in different tenses. And about your 3rd sentence, I think you need to change it. It's  not correct. You need something like, *If he had asked you about disobedience, you could/would tell her..*

Comment: @Avicenna Of the sentences, the third is the best composed of the three, and is perfectly grammatical (except for the disagreement in gender.)

Comment: *If he had asked you about disobedience, you could/would tell him...

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm struggling to understand time consistency in the 3rd sentence. Would you guide me a little bit ?

Comment: @Cardinal My apologies. It's the _fourth_ sentence that I meant to say is (to me) the best composed. The third is nonsensical from a temporal perspective.

Comment: @Avicenna Again my apologies. You're correct, the third is amiss.

Comment: I am not sure about the third sentence, but I certainly have seen sentences like this- If **you added** a screenshot of what you are trying to press, it would be helpful.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh The third sentence has a disagreement in time perpsective. The verb in the first clause is in the _past,_ which disagrees with the _present_ tense of the main verb _tell_ in the second. A correct version might be: _If he **asks** you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.If he asks you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

That’s right. It’s for talking about a situation in the future which the speaker thinks is quite possible.

> 2.If he will ask you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

*Will* after *if* shows insistence.

> *3.If he asked you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

This sentence is incorrect. The imperative isn't used with the second conditional. In order to express the same idea you can say,

> If he asked you about disobedience, you **could/should** tell him that I didn't listen to you as I always do.
>
> 4.If he should ask you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

SHOULD can be used after IF in clauses referring to the future to show that the indicated action is even less likely to happen.(If he happens to ask you...)

Comment: Imperative isn't used with **the** second conditional. I believe an article is missing.

Answer (score 2):

> If he asks you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

You are asking someone to tell him "I did not listen to you as I always do" if that person asks you about disobedience.

> If he will ask you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

"If he will ask you about disobedience" - this sounds like you are telling (in a strong manner, saying "You will X" as a command is a very authoritative way of speaking) a separate someone to ask you about disobedience.  So this is confusing.  Using *will* to refer to the future is not necessary here.

> If he asked you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

You are asking someone to tell him "I did not listen to you as I always do" if that person asked you about disobedience.  If they did not ask you, then they don't want you to tell him anything.

> If he should ask you about disobedience, tell him that I did not listen to you as I always do.

"If he should ask you about disobedience" - this sounds like you expect him to ask about disobedience, but there is a chance he may not ask you about disobedience.  There's no confusion here like there is with *will*.  This can sound a bit formal or authoritative but not as harsh as using *will*.

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts. Could you explain the third construction: **You are asking someone to tell him "I did not listen to you as I always do" if that person asked you about disobedience. If they did not ask you, then they don't want you to tell him anything**, please?